# How to avoid the error occur when ReportDataSource of RDLC is null?(No data are retrieved from DB)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rdlc

The Reportview controller will report an error

> An error has occurred during report processing.

when its datasource is null. But I think it should be a common scenario in most project. So, how you could alert a message instead of occur a error message on RDLC reportview controller？

Environment: VS2010 / Asp.net

Comment: I have found the solution. Just add a empty DataTable object to ReportDataSource....

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Just add a empty DataTable object to ReportDataSource..